# ClassNotFoundException While running on Cloud Server but works from Local Eclipse

Tags: java, spring-boot, reflection, classloader, classnotfoundexception

I have a Spring boot Project which Contains a DTO object. In one of our Jar we have a program to Read a file and create the DTO object. I am trying to load the DTO through Reflection. Its working perfectly from local eclipse workspace but when I deploy it in the cloud it fails, giving class not found exception. The below code is in the Jar which is added as maven dependendy.

```
    public class AbcFileReader<T extends ReaderInterface>{
        public List<T> readFile(File file, String className){
           T newObj = (T)Class.forName(className).newInstance();        
    }
```

Here `className = "com.abc.dto.AbcDTO";`Its implements ReaderInterface.java and the class is present in the package.
I have also tried the below line. But not working on cloud.

```
ClassLoader contextCL = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
T newObj = (T)Class.forName(className,true, contextCL).newInstance();
```

Comment: 1. This code won't compile 2. post the stack trace.

Comment: I corrected the File, It just says ClassNotFoundException at line xxx, I cant copy paste the stack trace as its not permissible from VDS...

Comment: What is the <scope> of the maven dependency ?

Comment: Didn't put any scope in maven

Comment: Then the class com.abc.dto.AbcDTO is not deployed to your "cloud" or your "cloud" environment has any limit on reading from the classpath. Can´t tell, as I don t know your deploy setup.

Comment: The DTO file is in the main Spring boot project.

Comment: `I corrected the File`, where ? This code won't compile. The method `readFile` has to return a `List<T>`. Probably you are not running the same code on local and remote.